# PHP - Scrape url (to get meta og:, meta link, or images)

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, thumbnails

I'm investigating about how to scrape a url in the "best and most recent way". I intend to retrieve one image from a url. First from a link tag `<link rel="image_src" href="http://stackoverflow.com/images/logo.gif" />`, then from an og tag... and maybe, if I still got nothing, try to get the first big enough img. Put differently, a light version of facebook on thumbnail-retrieving.

So I'm reading stuff on the internet, and when I thought I had found what I need it appeared the solution was pretty old (like 5-6y old http://www.lightspeedretail.com/cloud/blog/2007/08/scraping-links-with-php/) : solution using `cURL`, `DOMDocument`, and `XPath` basically. Then I would just have to work on the image url I got, store a few versions of it in different sizes for instance. But I'm fine for this part.

Would there be something better than this solution ? Ideally an example for the link tag would be fantastic.

Comment: cURL and DOM is the way to go here. That article is still valid.

Comment: This will work fine. I'm using Goutte for PHP web crawling, as it provides cookie storage and CSS selectors for link activation and form submission, but use whatever works. My policy is not to get it to be the best initially - get it working and into version control. You can then iteratively improve it from there. Remember that a slow working solution is much better than a theoretical fast version!

Comment: @Lyth Hi i want this ! :D can you help me ?